# Does "Poultry has given him great profit" use the word "Poultry" correctly?

Tags: grammaticality, nouns

> Poultry has given him great profit.

Is this sentence grammatically correct? What do you think is the correct use if this isn't correct?

Comment: Grammatically, yes... ish. Semantically, you'd probably want something more in there, because poultry itself probably isn't going to give anyone anything. For instance, "Selling poultry has given him great profit."

Comment: @aaamos I feel the the Noun Poultry isn't descriptive it can be _Poultry business_.

Comment: That's no better. "*His* poultry business has brought him great profit." Not just "Poultry business has..." because that means something rather different.

Comment: @aaamos and others; I agree that *poultry* on its own is not enough to convey the meaning, but there are other ways poultry can bring you profit besides selling it: you could run shows, sell eggs, or even be a famous chicken-portrait painter.

Comment: Google informs me that this is a study question, so I have added the "homework tag".

Comment: Unless you mean that his customers are mostly chickens, in which case you would say, "Poultry HAVE given him great profit."

Comment: Oddly, "He has had great profit from poultry" is rather better.

Comment: I would propose to make the sentence active.  "He has gained great profit from poultry"

Comment: His poultry profits were not paltry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help to add a bit more in there like "poultry production," "the poultry business," "the poultry farm" etc.

But since you're asking about its grammatical accuracy, the original sentence is fine.

It could also be used to emphasize the distinction "Poultry (not cattle) has given him great profit."

Comment: With some context - like talking around the areas of farming they are involved in - it makes sense as it stands. It does need context to interpret, but grammatically it is fine.